# State-of-the-art tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't know if this has been asked before (or possibly in other SEs), but a quick search didn't turn up anything.

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14182/8563) or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3309/8563) are questions that ask about, roughly, what recent developments mean in the grand scheme, or about what the state of the art is in some particular problem. Following on that line, I feel it could be productive add the tag [state-of-the-art](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-of-the-art) to questions asking things like "what's the best current ...", to put a marker on questions that will probably use a number of improved answers as time progresses and more physics is developed.

What are people's thoughts on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not be in favor of this. It is the nature of a Stack Exchange site that all questions are open to improved answers as time progresses. Besides, this tag sounds like a "meta tag," meaning that it doesn't really classify the content of the question, and we try to keep such tags to a minimum. There are a few that have become established through usage or necessity, like [homework](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), [research-level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-level), and [soft-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question), but we should carefully consider the benefits before introducing new ones, and I just don't think this tag would do enough to justify its existence.